# What was the title of short story by Ursula Le Guin about relativity of motion, from the point of view of tree?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ursula-k-le-guin

I'm trying to find a title of a short story by Ursula Le Guin (in some collection of short stories).  The story was told (as it turns out) from the point of view of tree, which talks about moving (relativity of motion), sometimes in two directions at once (two people / riders passing by said tree).  The story ends with car crashing into tree.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1366/

Comment: but the xkcd one is about Einstein's train joke, not about an oak. I doubt the oak has ever heard of Einstein.

Comment: @MrLister: both are (roughly) about relativity of motion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you’re looking for ***Direction of the Road***.

I haven’t read it myself (yet), but I found a synopsis [on Ekostories](http://ekostories.com/2013/05/16/le-guin-direction-of-the-road/) that sounds similar to the book you’re talking about:

> *Direction of the Road* is a scant seven pages, told from the perspective of a large oak situated by the side of a road. Inspired by a real tree living beside Highway 18 near McMinnville in Oregon, the protagonist believes it has the power to grow and shrink in size in relation to other organisms. It diligently uses this power to “uphold Relativity with dignity and the skill of long practice”.

It was originally published as part of *The Wind’s Twelve Quarters* in 1975, then republished in *The Unreal and the Real: Selected Stories, Volume One: Where on Earth* about two years ago.

Comment: This is the story where the tree messes up and ends up hitting a carload of teenagers?