# Subjectively Slowed Explorers Fight a Living Jungle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story (possibly published in Asimovs or Fantasy and Science Fiction, but not certain) involves explorers encountering a tribe that worships the local jungle as a god. They do so by taking a drug that slows them down so much they move and perceive at the same subjective rate as the growing plant life. This creates a situation where the jungle can attack them by growing vines towards them. So the jungle is not moving faster, the people are moving far slower than normal.

Publication time frame is before 1990, but it could easily be from much earlier.

Language: English

Comment: Is it Edmond Hamilton's ["Alien Earth"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41675), previously identified as the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72293/story-on-forest-timescale)? The full text is available at [UNZ.org](http://www.unz.org/Pub/ThrillingWonder-1949apr).

Comment: Ben got it! It is indeed "Alien Earth." Thank you, it has been nagging me for years.