# Short story about a potion that changes sense of time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Takes place in a tree plantation, maybe Vietnam. Locals and main character of the story drink a potion that slows down their bodies to the  point that to others they appear to be frozen in place but they themselves perceive tree branches and roots as moving fast. The trees and other plants try to ensnare and kill the main character. Read it in some best-of-science-fiction paperback for 1958, 59 or thereabouts.

Comment: This is a dupe.  Let me find the original.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85555/subjectively-slowed-explorers-fight-a-living-jungle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes! I'm pretty sure it is. I think it was part of an Asimov edited paperback.  Thank you!