# Short story about a drug that makes people live as slow as trees

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in Omni magazine about 25 years ago. In researching a few months ago, I believe I found info on this site, but can’t find again, and browser history was cleared. Written in the 40’s, I think.

Starts with one scientist coming to visit another about an experiment and upon arrival (an island, I think, tropical) finds a man just standing and staring. The scientist finds that his colleague had found a drug that slows body functions to the speed of trees, making people seem like zombie-statues. I don’t remember how it ends, so would like to read it again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the SFF SE :-) Is this the same story as the one asked about in the question: [story on forest timescale](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72293/story-on-forest-timescale)?

Comment: Yes, this is it!!!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could potentially be ["Alien Earth"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41675) (1949) by Edmond Hamilton. I found it by Googling `Short story drug people live as slow as trees` which turned up [this [story-identification]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72293/58193) question. The answer there has some relevant quotes but the top one seems most relevant:

> Farris lifted Berreau. The man's body was rigid, muscles locked in an effort no less strong because it was infinitely slow.
>
> He got the young Frenchman down on the stretcher, and then looked at the girl. "Can you help carry him? Or will you get a native?"
>
> She shook her head. "The tribesmen mustn't know of this. Andre isn't heavy."
>
> He wasn't. He was light as though wasted by fever, though the sickened Farris knew that it wasn't any fever that had done it.
>
> Why should a civilized young botanist go out into the forest and partake of a filthy primitive drug of some kind that slowed him down to a frozen stupor? It didn't make sense.

Comment: A good story, but it was never in *Omni*. According to the ISFDB the only magazine appearances were in *Thrilling Wonder stories* and *Urania* neither of which would be mistaken for *Omni*.

Comment: Thank you! I really have no idea where o read it if not Omni. Needless to say, the tone and some of the details stuck with me.